# A variable is still repeating at this depth error in macro

Tags: rust

I wrote the simple macro:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    {
        f($x:expr, $y:expr, $z:expr);
        $($c:expr => {
            $($m:expr => {
               $($s:expr => $b:expr),+
            }),+
        }),+
    } => {{
            match ($x, $y, $z) {
                $(
                ($c, $m, $s => $b),
                )+
            }
          }};
}

fn main(){

    let c = 0;
    let m = 0;
    let s = 0; 
    my_macro! {
        f (c, m, s);
        cc => {
            mm => {
                ss => b
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and it gets compiler errors:

```
error: variable 'm' is still repeating at this depth
  --> project/src/mod.rs
   |
39 |                 ($c, $m, $s => $b),
   |                              ^^^^^^^
```

I do not completely understand why it did happen.
Why and how to repair that?

Comment: Macro seems valid. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55fc1c21b234226f348132f5d3252c2e)

Comment: @Websterix try actually using the macro. That's where the error happens.

Answer (score 1):

In your rule for your macro,

```
f($x:expr, $y:expr, $z:expr);
$($c:expr => {
    $($m:expr => {
       $($s:expr => $b:expr),+
    }),+
}),+
```

`$x`, `$y` and `$z` bind a single `expr`. However, a whole list of `$c`s are bound. Moreover, associated to each `$c` is a whole list of `$m` because `$m` is still inside the `$(...).+` block associated with `$c`. For each of those `$m`s, a whole list of `$s`s is bound.

Now in your output,

```
{{
    match ($x, $y, $z) {
        $(
        ($c, $m, $s => $b),
        )+
    }
}};
```

you only unpack one layer of lists with `$(...)+`. After one layer, `$m` is still a list of expressions ("repeating"), so it can't be used directly. Remember that `$m` is really a list of lists (since there's a list of `$m` for each `$c`) and `$s` is really a list of lists of lists.

You're either going to need to restructure the rule so that there's only one `$m` and one `$s` for each `$c` (all within one `$(...),+`) or you're going to need to restructure the output so that `$m` and `$s` get unpacked an appropriate number of times.

After trying the first approach (a single `$(...),+` in the input rule), I'd suggest making `$c`, `$m` and `$s` patterns rather than expressions (as in `$c: pat` instead of `$c: expr`). This allows them to be used in the left side of a match branch.

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    {
        f($x:expr, $y:expr, $z:expr);
        $($c:pat => {
            $m:pat => {
               $s:pat => $b:expr
            }
        }),+
    } => {
            match ($x, $y, $z) {
                $(
                    ($c, $m, $s) => $b,
                )+
            }
          };
}
```

The real solution depends a lot on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: "or you're going to need to restructure the output so that $m and $s get unpacked an appropriate number of times." Can you help me with that? I cannot deal with that.

Comment: @J.Doe You just need to put another `$(...)+` *inside* the one you have now. Inside that second unpacking, `$m` gets unpacked twice (so it's just a single expression). To use `$s`, you'll have to put yet another `$(...)+` inside the second one. You'll get something like `$($c => $($m => $($s => $b)+)+)+` (this isn't correct as written, but it's the right idea). I don't really think that's what you want to do here, but if you explain exactly what you're going for, I can help with it.